# What's the Windows Phone 7 C# equivalent of the iOS call [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]?

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, ios, silverlight

Here is the iOS code I have:

```
[[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"en_US"]
```

Is there anything similar on the Windows Phone 7 C# side to find out what locality the user has chosen on their device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you would want to use

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

or

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
```

You can test for "en_US" with the `IetfLanguageTag` property

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag == "en_US"
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone please confirm this, but here's what I think the answer may be:

```
if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString() == "en-US")
```